# Facebook giving invalid token Facebook exception on login after reinstall

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

I am trying to Login on FB with latest FB Sdk.

Here is my code

```
Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
    Session session = new Session.Builder(v.getContext())
            .setApplicationId(getResources().getString(R.string.app_Id))
            .build();
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
    currentSession = session;
}
if (!currentSession.isOpened()) {
    Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null;
    openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(FBLogin.this);
    if (openRequest != null) {
        openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.EVERYONE);
        openRequest.setPermissions(PERMISSIONS);
        openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
        currentSession.addCallback(callback);
        currentSession.openForRead(openRequest);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Constants.RESULT_OK) {
        finish();
    } else Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
        resultCode, data);
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        registerWithServer(session);
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        Utilities
                .displayAlert(
                    "Oops!",
                    "Could not connect to Facebook. Try removing application"
                    + "from App dashboard", FBLogin.this);
    }
}
```

The code works fine when you first try to run it.But if the app is uninstalled or reinstalled and then you try to login, it opens FB Page, asks for permissions and then gives `FacebookException`, Invalid Token.

The only way I fix it by "Try removing application from App dashboard"

What is going on? How FB Tokens work? On reauthorizing it should create a new token instead of failing right?

Comment: You do not really expect an answer with this kind of formatting. Please post the code this `Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();` lines are from _properly formatted_

Comment: Which app are you reinstalling? Your own or Facebook's? It should work just fine reinstalling your app but is likely to produce the given message if you reinstall Facebook.

Comment: What's the exact FacebookException? Are you reinstalling from the same source (debug key?)

Comment: happens on both keys. the FacebookException, Invalid Authentication Token

Comment: What do you mean by "On reauthorizing it should create a new token instead of failing right?" Reauthorizing of what? Have you opened a Session previously from this app? If the initial state is CREATED, you should call openForRead/Write. If it's CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED, you should call openActiveSession to restore the previous session.

Comment: Have you set Sand Box mode disabled in your Basic info page of app on Facebook developers?

Comment: Try to implement facebook SDK implementation instead login via sso.

Answer (score 0):

```
          Try this code for facebook login

       Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

      // callback when session changes state
      @Override
      public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        if (session.isOpened()) {
            if(!session.getPermissions().contains("email"))
                    {
                session.requestNewReadPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(Facebookpersil.this, PERMISSIONS));
                    }

          // make request to the /me API
          Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              if (user != null) {

                  try
                  {

                Log.w("",""+user.asMap());
               name= user.getName();
            //   location=user.getLocation().getCity();
               nickname=user.asMap().get("username").toString();
               email=user.asMap().get("email").toString();
                String id=user.getId();
                URL img_value = null;
                try {
                    img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=small");
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                fbprofileimage=img_value.toString();
                session.close();
                if(email.length()==0)
                {
                    Toast("Unexpected error. Please try again");
                    finish();
                }
                else{
                    new Loginauth().execute();
                }
                  }
                  catch(Exception e)
                  {
                      Log.w("error", e.toString());
                  }
                }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });




  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
```